# Swift solution to Leetcode “Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters”

Tags: strings, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, swift

From [LeetCode medium 3. Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/):

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.
>
> Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.
>
> Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", with the length of 3. Note that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.

Here is my solution, but the online judge told me "Time Limit Exceeded". Is there a better solution to this problem?

```
private extension String
{
    subscript (index:Int) -> Character
    {
        return (self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(index)])
    }
}

class Solution
{
    func lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String) -> Int
    {
        var str:String = ""
        var longest:Int = Int.min

        if s.isEmpty
        {
            return 0
        }

        for i in 0...s.characters.count-1
        {
            if !str.characters.contains(s[i])
            {
                str += String(s[i])
            }

            else
            {
                longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
                str = ""

            }
        }

        return longest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Swift standard library does not have a built-in method to access the
n'th character of a string. It is tempting to fill that gap with a custom
extension like you did, but the problem is that

```
self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(index)]
```

is a \$ O(index) \$  operation. In contrast to other languages where a
"character" is a fixed-size object (and accessing the n'th character of
a string a  \$ O(1) \$  operation), a Swift `Character` represents a 
"Unicode grapheme cluster" which consists of one or more Unicode scalar
values, see e.g. [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30) in the Swift blog.

That makes

```
for i in 0...s.characters.count-1 {
    // access `s[i]` with your custom subscript method
}
```

a `O(n^2)` operation where `n` is the number of characters in the string.
It is much more efficient to *iterate* over the characters with

```
for c in s.characters {
    // do something with `c`
}
```

More remarks:

- The explicit type annotations in

  ```
  var str:String = ""
  var longest:Int = Int.min
  ```

  are not necessary, the compiler can infer the type automatically.
- If you start with `var longest = 0` then the special case

  ```
  if s.isEmpty
  {
      return 0
  }
  ```

  becomes obsolete.
- There are actually two errors in your code. If a repeating
  character is found then the new substring candidate consists of
  that character, i.e.

  ```
   longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
   str = ""
  ```

  should be

  ```
   longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
   str = String(s[i])
  ```

  otherwise `lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcdd")` returns `3` instead
  of `4`.

  And the longest substring length must also be updated at the *end*
  of the string:

  ```
  longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
  return longest
  ```

  otherwise `lengthOfLongestSubstring("aabcd")` returns `1` instead
  of `4`.

Putting all that together, the method becomes

```
func lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String) -> Int {
    var str = ""
    var longest = 0

    for c in s.characters {
        if !str.characters.contains(c) {
            str.append(c)
        } else {
            longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
            str = String(c)
        }
    }
    longest = max(longest, str.characters.count)
    return longest
}
```

which should be faster than your code.

Another possible improvement is to store the characters of the
current substring in an `Array` or a `Set` instead of a `String`.
Which one is faster depends on the size of the strings, here is
an example with an array:

```
func lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String) -> Int {
    var substringChars: [Character] = []
    var longest = 0

    for c in s.characters {
        if !substringChars.contains(c) {
            substringChars.append(c)
        } else {
            longest = max(longest, substringChars.count)
            substringChars = [c]
        }
    }
    longest = max(longest, substringChars.count)
    return longest
}
```

As of **Swift 4,** a Swift string is a collection of its characters
again, so  `for c in s.characters` can be simplified to `for c in s`.

Comment: note this won't work on a string like "dvdf"

Comment: @AndyRoid: Yes, you are right. I reviewed the given code, but did not recognize that it has a flaw. Apparently  that has been addressed in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to work for me. The else of Martin didn't work for me. Ex. string "abacdef" gives me 5 as the length of the longest substring with the substring being "acdef". The longest substring in this case should be "bacdef" with length 6.

```
func lengthOfLongestSubstring(s: String) -> Int {
    var str = ""
    var longest = 0

    for c in s {
        if !str.contains(c) {
            str.append(c)
        } else {
            longest = max(longest, str.count)
            let index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            if str[..<index] == String(c) {
                str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: String(c), with: "")
            } else {
                if let index = str.index(of: c) {
                    let nextIndex = str.index(after: index)
                    str = String(str[nextIndex...])
                }
            }
            str.append(c)
        }
    }
    longest = max(longest, str.count)
    return longest
}
```